# How do take inputted values from a html form and convert to a csv?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, csv, web

So i want to take a couple of values from an HTML input-form, and basically be able to generate a csv file to download for the user when they click a button which will consist of the data they entered into the form. However, I am confused about how i would go about this and can't find a good guide online.

I also would like to customize how the csv format will be if possible, hope somehow knows what iam trying to do! thanks.

Edit: iam not asking to do this in just html, i assume javascript is best option

MY HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>UniWeighter</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"/>
    <script
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js">
    </script>
  </head>

<body>

    <style>
        body {
           background-image: url("images/background.png");
        }
     </style>

    <section class="section">
        <div class="container is-centered is-mobile">
            <div class="content has-text-centered">
                <h1><b>UniWeighter</b></h1>
                <h2>Weighted Average Grade Calculator</h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="box">
                    <p>
                        This Simple Grade Calculator will determine your average grade for your assignments,
                        end of year grade or end of university grade.
                        <br>
                        The weighted average simply takes into account how much each course is worth when calculating the average.
                        <br>
                        This calculator can also be used to calculate any weighted average, not just courses.
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                

                <div class="column is-two-quarter is is-offset-two-quarter is-mobile">
                    <div class="box">
                        <article class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <figure class="image is-64x64">
                            <img src="images/help.png" alt="Image">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-content">
                            <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                <strong>How does it actually work?</strong> <small>Just one example below</small>
                                <br>
                                Lets say you want to find a end of module final mark. You have 2 total exams/assignments for that module.
                                One worth <b>40%</b> weighting and you get <b>75/100</b> marks, the other worth <b>60%</b> weighting and you get <b>62/100</b>.
                                So you can type in 40 for the weight and 75 for the grade on first row, also 60 and 62 for the next row.
                                Press Calculate and you find you got an overall average mark of <b>67.2</b> and a grade of <b>2:1</b> for that module.
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="columns is-centered">
                <div class="column is-three-quarters">

                    <div class="card">
                        <br>
                        <div class="columns is-gapless is-multiline is-mobile">
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">The Entry</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Grade (%)</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Weight (Credits)</h1>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                    <div class="card-content">
                        <form id="grade-form">
                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">1</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right ">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">2</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">3</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">4</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">5</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">6</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">7</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" id="grade7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" id="credit7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control">
                            <button id="submit" class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is-outlined">
                            Calculate
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control">
                            <button id="download" class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is-outlined">
                            Get CSV file of data
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- RESULTS -->
    <section class="section is-centered is-mobile is-paddingless"> 
        <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Calculated Results</h1>
        <div class="columns is-multiline is-centered">
        
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen ">
                <div class="notification is-success is-light has-text">
                <p id="averageGrade" class="title is-1"><i class="fa fa-percentage"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Average Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen">
                <div class="notification is-link is-light has-text">
                <p id="formalGrade" class="title is-1"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Formal Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <br>
    <div class="line" style="padding: 1%;">
        <hr>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="content has-text-centered">
          <p>
              <br><br>
            <strong>UniWeighter</strong> by <a href="https://mathewsjoy.herokuapp.com/">Mathews Joy</a>. The source code is licensed
            <a href="http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php">MIT</a>. <strong>Share -</strong> 
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/" aria-label="reply">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/" aria-label="retweet">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/&title=Checkout%20Uniweighter!&summary=&source=" aria-label="like">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </nav>
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>


</body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn the format of CSV (it's very simple) and you'll be able to do it. CSV format is `value,value,value` for columns, and newline for rows. Also, you may want to place the columns in an array, where each entry is a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("#download").addEventListener('click', generateCSV);
  
  function generateCSV(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('grade-form'));
    const formObj = Object.fromEntries(formdata);
    const len = Object.keys(formObj).length/2;
    let formValues = '';
    for(let i=1; i<= len; i++){
       // comma separated values and break line
        formValues += formObj['grade'+i] +','+formObj['credit'+i]+ "\r\n";
    }
    downloadCSV(formValues);
  }
  
  function downloadCSV(formValues){
    const columnNames = "Grade (%), Weight (Credits)";
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    csvContent += columnNames + "\r\n";
    csvContent += formValues + "\r\n";

    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my-form-data.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    // link.remove();
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>UniWeighter</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css"/>
    <script
      src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js">
    </script>
  </head>

<body>

    <style>
        body {
           background-image: url("images/background.png");
        }
     </style>

    <section class="section">
        <div class="container is-centered is-mobile">
            <div class="content has-text-centered">
                <h1><b>UniWeighter</b></h1>
                <h2>Weighted Average Grade Calculator</h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="box">
                    <p>
                        This Simple Grade Calculator will determine your average grade for your assignments,
                        end of year grade or end of university grade.
                        <br>
                        The weighted average simply takes into account how much each course is worth when calculating the average.
                        <br>
                        This calculator can also be used to calculate any weighted average, not just courses.
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                

                <div class="column is-two-quarter is is-offset-two-quarter is-mobile">
                    <div class="box">
                        <article class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <figure class="image is-64x64">
                            <img src="images/help.png" alt="Image">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-content">
                            <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                <strong>How does it actually work?</strong> <small>Just one example below</small>
                                <br>
                                Lets say you want to find a end of module final mark. You have 2 total exams/assignments for that module.
                                One worth <b>40%</b> weighting and you get <b>75/100</b> marks, the other worth <b>60%</b> weighting and you get <b>62/100</b>.
                                So you can type in 40 for the weight and 75 for the grade on first row, also 60 and 62 for the next row.
                                Press Calculate and you find you got an overall average mark of <b>67.2</b> and a grade of <b>2:1</b> for that module.
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>

                <div class="columns is-centered">
                <div class="column is-three-quarters">

                    <div class="card">
                        <br>
                        <div class="columns is-gapless is-multiline is-mobile">
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">The Entry</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Grade (%)</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column is-one-third has-text-centered is-size-5">
                                <h1 class="has-text-weight-semibold">Weight (Credits)</h1>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                    <div class="card-content">
                    
                        <form id="grade-form">
                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">1</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right ">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade1" id="grade1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit1" id="credit1" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">2</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade2" id="grade2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit2" id="credit2" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">3</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade3" id="grade3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit3" id="credit3" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">4</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade4" id="grade4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit4" id="credit4" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">5</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade5" id="grade5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit5" id="credit5" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">6</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade6" id="grade6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit6" id="credit6" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="level">
                            <!-- Left side -->
                            <div class="level-left is-marginless">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <p class="number">7</p>
                                Assignment/Module
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Right side -->
                            <div class="level-right">
                            <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                <div class="control has-icons-right">
                                    <input class="input" name="grade7" id="grade7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-percentage"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="level-right">
                                <div class="level-item">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control has-icons-left ">
                                    <input class="input" name="credit7" id="credit7" type="number" />
                                    <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                                        <i class="fas fa-coins"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control">
                            <button id="submit" class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is-outlined">
                            Calculate
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control">
                            <button id="download" class="button is-large is-fullwidth is-primary is-outlined">
                                Get CSV file of data
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- RESULTS -->
    <section class="section is-centered is-mobile is-paddingless"> 
        <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Calculated Results</h1>
        <div class="columns is-multiline is-centered">
        
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen ">
                <div class="notification is-success is-light has-text">
                <p id="averageGrade" class="title is-1"><i class="fa fa-percentage"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Average Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-12-tablet is-6-desktop is-3-widescreen">
                <div class="notification is-link is-light has-text">
                <p id="formalGrade" class="title is-1"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></p>
                <p class="subtitle is-4">Formal Grade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <br>
    <div class="line" style="padding: 1%;">
        <hr>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="content has-text-centered">
          <p>
              <br><br>
            <strong>UniWeighter</strong> by <a href="https://mathewsjoy.herokuapp.com/">Mathews Joy</a>. The source code is licensed
            <a href="http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php">MIT</a>. <strong>Share -</strong> 
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/" aria-label="reply">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/" aria-label="retweet">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3A//uniweighter.netlify.app/&title=Checkout%20Uniweighter!&summary=&source=" aria-label="like">
                    <span class="icon is-small">
                        <i class="fab fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </nav>
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>
</body>
<!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Takes all input names as columnNames and append to csv content as the first row (column names)

```
const columnNames = Object.keys(formObj).map(key => key.toUpperCase()).join(",");
let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
csvContent += columnNames + "\r\n";
```

Take out all form values and append to csv content.

Lets say user has entered address value as `New Braunfels, TX, 78130`
Since its commma separated, for this CSV will create 3 column entries `New Braunfels`, `TX`, and `78130`.
To handle this we will replace `,` with   so that it will add it in one column

```
const formValues = Object.values(formObj).map(val => val.replaceAll(',', ' ')).join(",");
csvContent += formValues + "\r\n";
```

```js
function downloadCSV(){
    const formEl = document.forms.userForm;
    const formData = new FormData(formEl);
    const formObj = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    const columnNames = Object.keys(formObj).map(key => key.toUpperCase()).join(",");
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
    csvContent += columnNames + "\r\n";
    const formValues = Object.values(formObj).map(val => val.replaceAll(',', ' ')).join(",");
    csvContent += formValues + "\r\n";
       // Set encoded csvContent as `href` attribute and also set download attribute to set the file name
    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    const link = document.querySelector("#downloadRef");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "my-form-data.csv");
}
```

```html
<form id="userForm">
    <div><label>Name<input type="text" name="name"></label></div>
    <div><label>Age<input type="number" name="age"></label></div>
    <div>
        Gender
        <label>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"></label>
        <label>Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"></label>
    </div>
    <div><label>Address<textarea name="address"></textarea></label></div>
    <button onclick="downloadCSV()">
        <a id="downloadRef"style="text-decoration:none" href="#">Create CSV</a>
    </button>
</form>
```

After setting `csvContent` as href attribute, the click event will be taken care of by [Event capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

*This snippet will not download CSV file here, run code on your host

Comment: looks good, so i assume i could have mutliple input field and just make multiple const data = document.querySelector('#data').value; for each field right? also can you explain what var link = document.createElement("a"); is doing exactly?

Comment: @patricebailey1998 edited answer for multiple form inputs and added first csv row entries as input names.

Comment: hello iam trying to implemnt the code now for my project however cant quite get it too work, can you see what my javascript would neeed to be, ive added my html from my project to the question. I basically need to get the data from all the "Grades" and "Weights", and have a new csv row per grade and weight for each "assignment/module", thanks.

Comment: will your form inputs change in future?

Comment: so this is the project I have currently https://uniweighter.netlify.app/, so for exaple they can enter the specfic fields, and then click download csv button and it will download the csv, but if they enter new values it should be able to download a new csv with updated data, thanks